# Bootstrap Template into Code Igniter - Can't get resource file

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to integrate a Bootstrap template into codeigniter but i just cannot get the right path for my resource file such as css or javascript.

This is what i've done so far.

1)Virtual Host on apache

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/code_igniter_template/"
ServerName local.codeigniter
</VirtualHost>
```

2)Inside \application\views\  i've created a new "pages" folder that contains home.php and about.php

3Config.php file

```
<?php 
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
$config['base_url'] = 'http://local.codeigniter/';
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
$config['url_suffix'] = '';
$config['language'] = 'english';
$config['charset'] = 'UTF-8';
$config['enable_hooks'] = FALSE;
$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_';
$config['composer_autoload'] = FALSE;
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';
$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;
$config['controller_trigger'] = 'c';
$config['function_trigger'] = 'm';
$config['directory_trigger'] = 'd';
$config['allow_get_array'] = TRUE;
$config['log_threshold'] = 0;
$config['log_path'] = '';
$config['log_file_extension'] = '';
$config['log_file_permissions'] = 0644;
$config['log_date_format'] = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
$config['error_views_path'] = '';
$config['cache_path'] = '';
$config['cache_query_string'] = FALSE;
$config['encryption_key'] = '';


$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;


$config['cookie_prefix']    = '';
$config['cookie_domain']    = '';
$config['cookie_path']      = '/';
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
$config['cookie_httponly']  = FALSE;


$config['standardize_newlines'] = FALSE;


$config['global_xss_filtering'] = FALSE;


$config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;
$config['csrf_token_name'] = 'csrf_test_name';
$config['csrf_cookie_name'] = 'csrf_cookie_name';
$config['csrf_expire'] = 7200;
$config['csrf_regenerate'] = TRUE;
$config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = array();


$config['compress_output'] = FALSE;


$config['time_reference'] = 'local';


$config['rewrite_short_tags'] = FALSE;


$config['proxy_ips'] = '';
```

Create a controller pages.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Alessandro Curia
 * Date: 01/07/2017
 * Time: 23:52
 */

class Pages extends CI_Controller {

    function view ($page='home'){

        $this->load->helper('url');

        if(!file_exists('application/views/pages/'.$page.'.php')){
            show_404();
            echo('<h1>file not found</h1>');
        }

        $this->load->view('pages/'.$page.'.php');

    }

}
```

I've create an .htacces file in my root folder as follow

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|vandor|css|img|fonts|js|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

routes.php file

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';

$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';

$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

As you can see I've set the base_url and i'm trying to get the full path in the html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Creative - Start Bootstrap Theme</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather:400,300,300italic,400italic,700,700italic,900,900italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <!-- Plugin CSS -->
    <link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>vendor/magnific-popup/magnific-popup.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Theme CSS -->
    <link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/creative.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body id="page-top">

<!-- etc etc -->

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Plugin JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>vendor/scrollreveal/scrollreveal.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>vendor/magnific-popup/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>

<!-- Theme JavaScript -->
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/creative.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

the path the browser is looking for it's like http://local.codeigniter/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css

(which is the right location of file)

but when i put this url in the browser i got 404 error.

Any idea what 's going on?

Comment: In `.htaccess` rule you mistyped `vandor`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try the htaccess file from the user guide that works out of the box... It has always worked for me.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```